# Profiling maven web application with JProfiler

Tags: java, maven-2, jprofiler

I know I can profile my application with JProfiler using ANT target. Is there a way to do the same with maven??
Actually maven allows to run ant targets, using maven-ant plugin, but I'd like to perform such profiling without ANT.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JVM arguments normally used to enable profiling of the application can be added to the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable. These arguments will also be used for all applications started by Maven.

As an example my MAVEN_OPTS to enable remote debugging on a Jetty instance started by Maven:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS = "-Xmx512m -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4000"
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply Ruben! But it seems to be a bit different from what I wanted...  
Configuring maven in that way will force the profiler to run every time the application is run. Am I right??

Comment: When the application is started through Maven (so not when deployed as a war, or when started from outside of Maven) it will always be possible to profile the application. This does not mean the profiler needs to be started and attached everytime.

Comment: @Ruben I know it's been 2+ years n all.. but were exactly do we add the MAVEN_OPTS? In Environment Variables? And if we do that, does the maven install startup the Profiler? (cos it didnt change anything for me)

Comment: @Chillax I believe the MAVEN_OPTS can be added to the environment variables. Starting Maven does not start the profile, with the correct options set it simply allows the profile to attach to the running Java process. You need to start VisualVM, JPRofiler or … yourself.

Comment: @Ruben The profiler which I use needs some changes in catalina.bat file (JAVA_OPTS to be set) so that the code is profiled during startup. How can u do that via Maven. I am able to start it through tomcat i manually downloaded. But the one which maven downloads doesnt have a catalina.bat. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Chillax If you need to profile an appliation running in Tomcat you do not need to start it through Maven. Simply deploy the war in Tomcat configured with the correct debug options. Otherwise, change suspend=n to suspend=y , then the aaplication will wait for your profiler to attach.

Answer (score 0):

It is driven by JVM arguments and some environment entry. See http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/ for more details at "Requirements for remote profiling" chapter. There is the remote application profiling wizard, and it also tells you what to do exactly. You should do the following:

1.4 JVM LINUX:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable should contain profiler/bin

1.4 JVM Windows:
PATH environment variable should contain profiler/bin

1.4 Both:
Add -Xrunjprofiler -Xbootclasspath/a:{path to agent.jar} JVM arguments

Above 1.5:
-agentpath:[path to jprofilerti library] should be added to JVM arguments